# pinging from GNS3 router to Ubuntu bridged network and vice versa

Tags: networking, routing

I have installed Vmware on Ubuntu Server and created multiple VMs and connect them to different VMnet adapters. Actually I created 30 VMnet on the server. So I have the physical network adapter in adition to all of those VM network adapters.

I connect my physical adapter to my laptop which has Windows7 and I share my wireless internet connection to my physical NIC which is connected to the p NIC on the server.

I installed GNS3 and add a router with 2 interfaces, the first one is bridged to the physical interface and it could get an IP address and connect to internet.

the second interface is configured with a different network.

I can ping both networks from into the router, and I could ping the first interface on the router that facing the internet from my laptop (Windows7) ***but I could not ping the ip configured on the second interface which is on a different network.***

when I tried to ping both interfaces on the router from into Ubuntu server, there is no connection, how come and vice versa, although I disabled the firewall on Ubuntu. But I could ping windows (my laptop) IP address from into the router.

how can I make my GNS3 router ping to my bridged NIC ip address on Ubuntu server and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux / Unix / OS X, when you bridge a router or switch interface to your local Ubuntu host you can’t ping it from your host. But this works on Windows? What gives?

This does generally work on Windows (depending on your network card) but not on Linux / Unix. Most likely this is due to differences between libpcap and Winpcap, and the differences in the network stacks on Unix / Windows (e.g. NDIS). However you should be able to ping your bridged interfaces from other systems on the bridged network. If this does not work on Windows for your particular NIC, try creating a Windows loopback adapter and bridging to that. On Linux you can use a tap interface and the NIO_tap (available from a cloud). OS X you can install tun/tap drivers.